# python AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'show' using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Weird error maybe caused by matplotlib?

```
asd=bp.plot_measurements(ps[:, 0], ps[:, 1])
asd.show()
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'show'
```

and this is the definition:

```
def plot_measurements(xs, ys=None, color='k', lw=2,  label='Measurements', lines=False, **kwargs):
    """ Helper function to give a consistant way to display
    measurements in the book.
    """

    plt.autoscale(tight=True)
    if lines:
        if ys is not None:
            return plt.plot(xs, ys, color=color, lw=lw, ls='--', 
    label=label, **kwargs)
        else:
            return plt.plot(xs, color=color, lw=lw, ls='--', label=label, 
    **kwargs)
    else:
        if ys is not None:
            return plt.scatter(xs, ys, edgecolor=color, facecolor='none',
                        lw=2, label=label, **kwargs),
        else:
            return plt.scatter(range(len(xs)), xs, edgecolor=color, 
    facecolor='none', lw=2, label=label, **kwargs)
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: It looks your `bp.plot_measurements` returns a tuple of objects. Why don't you call `plt.show()` instead?

Comment: @user128285  im using a kalman filter library that implements that definition. cant really change how it was implemented. only thing i can do is find a way to plot what it reutrns

Comment: @snakecharmerb if i remove the trailing commas i get this error `AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'show'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `plot_measurements` has several possible return types. It can be a tuple of lines (if `lines == True`) or a Collection or a tuple of Collections (if `lines ==False`).

In all of the three possible cases, the return type is an object which does not have a `show()` method.

Instead you probably want to call `plt.show()`, where `plt` is `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: thanks to your comment and @user128285 's comment, it worked.